# Using generators + promises to do "simulated synchronous" communication in/with a Firefox SDK add-on

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, generator, firefox-addon-sdk

**TL;DR: Is there any way to rewrite this callback-based JavaScript code to use promises and generators instead?**

### Background

I have a Firefox extension written using the Firefox [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK).  As usual for the SDK, the code is split into an *add-on script* and a [*content script*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts).  The two scripts have different kinds of privileges: add-on scripts can do fancy things such as, for example, calling native code through the [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes) interface, while content scripts can interact with web pages.  However, add-on scripts and content scripts can only interact with *each other* through an asynchronous [message-passing interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Communicating_with_the_add-on).

I want to be able to call extension code from a user script on an ordinary, unprivileged web page.  This can be done using a mechanism called [`exportFunction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.exportFunction) that lets one, well, export a function from extension code to user code.  So far, so good.  <del>However, one can only use `exportFunction` in a content script, not an add-on script.</del>  That would be fine, except that the function I need to export needs to use the aforementioned js-ctypes interface, which can only be done in an add-on script.

**(Edit: it turns out to *not* be the case that you can only use `exportFunction` in a content script.  See the comment below.)**

To get around this, I wrote a "wrapper" function in the content script; this wrapper is the function I actually export via `exportFunction`.  I then have the wrapper function call the "real" function, over in the add-on script, by passing a message to the add-on script.  Here's what the content script looks like; it's exporting the function `lengthInBytes`:

```js
// content script

function lengthInBytes(arg, callback) {
    self.port.emit("lengthInBytesCalled", arg);

    self.port.on("lengthInBytesReturned", function(result) {
        callback(result);
    });
}

exportFunction(lengthInBytes, unsafeWindow, {defineAs: "lengthInBytes",
                                             allowCallbacks: true});
```

And here's the add-on script, where the "real" version of `lengthInBytes` is defined.  The code here listens for the content script to send it a `lengthInBytesCalled` message, then calls the real version of `lengthInBytes`, and sends back the result in a `lengthInBytesReturned` message.  (In real life, of course, I probably wouldn't need to use js-ctypes to get the length of a string; this is just a stand-in for some more interesting C library call.  Use your imagination. :) )

```js
// add-on script

// Get "chrome privileges" to access the Components object.
var {Cu, Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");

Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: ["*", "file://*"],
    attachTo: ["existing", "top"],
    contentScriptFile: data.url("content.js"),
    contentScriptWhen: "start", // Attach the content script before any page script loads.

    onAttach: function(worker) {
        worker.port.on("lengthInBytesCalled", function(arg) {
            let result = lengthInBytes(arg);
            worker.port.emit("lengthInBytesReturned", result);
        });
    }
});

function lengthInBytes(str) {
    // str is a JS string; convert it to a ctypes string.
    let cString = ctypes.char.array()(str);

    libc.init();
    let length = libc.strlen(cString); // defined elsewhere
    libc.shutdown();

    // `length` is a ctypes.UInt64; turn it into a JSON-serializable
    // string before returning it.
    return length.toString();
}
```

Finally, the user script (which will only work if the extension is installed) looks like this:

```js
// user script, on an ordinary web page
lengthInBytes("hello", function(result) {
    console.log("Length in bytes: " + result);
});
```

### What I want to do

Now, the call to `lengthInBytes` in the user script is an asynchronous call; instead of returning a result, it "returns" its result in its callback argument.  But, after seeing [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qbKWsbJ76-s) about using promises and generators to make async code easier to understand, I'm wondering how to rewrite this code in that style.

Specifically, what I want is for `lengthInBytes` to return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility) that somehow represents the eventual payload of the `lengthInBytesReturned` message.  Then, in the user script, I'd have a generator that evaluated `yield lengthInBytes("hello")` to get the result.

But, even after watching the above-linked video and reading about promises and generators, I'm still stumped about how to hook this up.  A version of `lengthInBytes` that returns a `Promise` would look something like:

```js
function lengthInBytesPromise(arg) {
    self.port.emit("lengthInBytesCalled", arg);

    return new Promise(
        // do something with `lengthInBytesReturned` event???  idk.
    );
}
```

and the user script would involve something like

```js
var result = yield lengthInBytesPromise("hello");
console.log(result);
```

but that's as much as I've been able to figure out.  How would I write this code, and what would the user script that calls it look like?  Is what I want to do even possible?

[A complete working example of what I have so far is here.](https://github.com/lkuper/addon-playground/tree/master/taskjs-ctypes)

**Thanks for your help!**

Comment: There's an alternate approach to this problem that involves calling `exportFunction` from the add-on script, and therefore avoids the whole issue of having to use wrapper functions to communicate between the add-on script and the content script. So, if you don't care about how to use promises and generators as an alternative to callbacks, and you just want to export synchronous functions from privileged add-on code, an example of an extension that uses that approach is [here](https://github.com/mozkeeler/signTextJS/blob/master/lib/main.js) -- thanks to David Keeler for the suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A really elegant solution to this problem is coming in the next *next* version of JavaScript, ECMAScript 7, in the form of [`async` functions](http://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/), which are a marriage of `Promise`s and generators that sugars over the warts of both. More on that at the very bottom of this answer.

I'm the author of [Regenerator](https://github.com/facebook/regenerator), a transpiler that supports `async` functions in browsers today, but I realize it might be overkill to suggest you introduce a compilation step into your add-on development process, so I'll focus instead on the questions you're actually asking: how does one design a sensible `Promise`-returning API, and what is the nicest way to consume such an API?

First of all, here's how I would implement `lengthInBytesPromise`:

```js
function lengthInBytesPromise(arg) {
  self.port.emit("lengthInBytesCalled", arg);

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    self.port.on("lengthInBytesReturned", function(result) {
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
}
```

The `function(resolve, reject) { ... }` callback is invoked immediately when the promise is instantiated, and the `resolve` and `reject` parameters are callback functions that can be used to provide the eventual value for the promise.

If there was some possibility of failure in this example, you could pass an `Error` object to the `reject` callback, but it seems like this operation is infallible, so we can just ignore that case here.

So that's how an API creates promises, but how do consumers consume such an API? In your content script, the simplest thing to do is to call `lengthInBytesPromise` and interact with the resulting `Promise` directly:

```js
lengthInBytesPromise("hello").then(function(length) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

In this style, you put the code that depends on the result of `lengthInBytesPromise` in a callback function passed to the `.then` method of the promise, which may not seem like a huge improvement over callback hell, but at least the indentation is more manageable if you're chaining a longer series of asynchronous operations:

```js
lengthInBytesPromise("hello").then(function(length) {
  console.log(result);
  return someOtherPromise(length);
}).then(function(resultOfThatOtherPromise) {
  return yetAnotherPromise(resultOfThatOtherPromise + 1);
}).then(function(finalResult) {
  console.log(finalResult);
});
```

Generators can help reduce the boilerplate here, but additional runtime support is necessary. Probably the easiest approach is to use Dave Herman's [task.js library](http://taskjs.org/):

```js
spawn(function*() { // Note the *; this is a generator function!
  var length = yield lengthInBytesPromise("hello");
  var resultOfThatOtherPromise = yield someOtherPromise(length);
  var finalResult = yield yetAnotherPromise(resultOfThatOtherPromise + 1);
  console.log(finalResult);
});
```

This code is a lot shorter and less callback-y, that's for sure. As you can guess, most of the magic has simply been moved into the `spawn` function, but its implementation is actually pretty straightforward.

The `spawn` function takes a generator function and invokes it immediately to get a generator object, then invokes the `gen.next()` method of the generator object to get the first `yield`ed promise (the result of `lengthInBytesPromise("hello")`), then waits for that promise to be fulfilled, then invokes `gen.next(result)` with the result, which provides a value for the first `yield` expression (the one assigned to `length`) and causes the generator function to run up to the next `yield` expression (namely, `yield someOtherPromise(length)`), producing the next promise, and so on, until there are no more promises left to await, because the generator function finally returned.

To give you a taste of what's coming in ES7, here's how you might use an `async` function to implement exactly the same thing:

```
async function process(arg) {
  var length = await lengthInBytesPromise(arg);
  var resultOfThatOtherPromise = await someOtherPromise(length);
  var finalResult = await yetAnotherPromise(resultOfThatOtherPromise + 1);
  return finalResult;
}

// An async function always returns a Promise for its own return value.
process(arg).then(function(finalResult) {
  console.log(finalResult);
});
```

All that's really happening here is that the `async` keyword has replaced the `spawn` function (and the `*` generator syntax), and `await` has replaced `yield`. It's not a huge leap, but it will be really nice to have this syntax built into the language instead of having to rely on an external library like task.js.

If you're excited about using `async` functions instead of task.js, then by all means check out [Regenerator](http://facebook.github.io/regenerator/)!

Comment: Hey, first thing - props for regenerators. I value that tool. Second of all - consider recommending and using faster tools which better debugging ability - task.js is rather slow where for example Bluebird coroutines are faster than callbacks + closures.

Comment: Your edits, however, were not correct, so I had to roll them back. Please be careful when editing other people's answers!

Comment: @Ben: He surely meant `self.port.on("lengthInBytesReturned", resolve);`

Comment: Whoops - yes that's what I meant, sorry - editing from mobile sucks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the Promise is built by wrapping your original callback inside the resolve/reject function:

```
function lengthInBytesPromise(arg) {
    self.port.emit("lengthInBytesCalled", arg);

    let returnVal = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        self.port.on("lengthInBytesReturned", function(result) {
            if (result) { // maybe some kind of validity check
                resolve(result);
            } else {
                reject("Something went wrong?");
            }
        }
    });

    return returnVal;
}
```

Basically, it'd create the Promise and return it immediately, while the inside of the Promise kicks off and then handles the async task. I think at the end of the day someone has to take the callback-style code and wrap it up.

Your user would then do something like

```
lengthInBytesPromise(arg).then(function(result) {
    // do something with the result
});
```

Comment: I was going to answer with the same, but noticed that he discussed using generators and yield, which I'm not familiar with. I think he's trying to avoid the `then` syntax. See the end of @Ben's answer.

Comment: Ha, what an embarrassingly chauvinistic misconception. I'm sorry.